# how can i set the gap limit in cplex?

Tags: settings, cplex

I would like to set the 30% gap limit. How can I do this using the setting file? I tried to modify the MIP tolerance part setting "relative MIP gap tolerance" to 0,30 but  after run going to the engine log part, it doesn't appear that cplex has set this gap. How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: How are you using CPLEX? Which version of CPLEX? Which API and programming langauge?

Answer (score 0):

In OPL you would write

```
execute
{
cplex.epgap=0.3;
}
```

and if you use a .ops file (settings) do not forget to add the .ops file to the run configuration.

[image]